# How to fix Duplicate Key IllegalStateException while using Collectors.toMap()

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have a stream that processes some strings and collects them in a map.

But getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Duplicate key test@yahoo.com
(attempted merging values [test@yahoo.com] and [test@yahoo.com])
at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.duplicateKeyException(Collectors.java:133)
```

I'm using the following code:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = emails.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Function.identity(),
        email -> processEmails(email)
    ));
```

Comment: What does the method `processEmails` do?

Comment: Your input `emails` contains duplicate values, so isn't suitable to add to a Map unless you resolve merging the values for matched keys or filter the duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flavor of `toMap()` you're using in your code (which expects only `keyMapper` and `valueMapper`) disallow duplicates merely because it's not capable to handle them. And exception message explicitly tells you that.

*Judging by the resulting type `Map<String, List<String>>` and by the exception message which shows strings enclosed in square brackets, it is possible to make the conclusion that `processEmails(email)` produces a `List<String>` (although it's not obvious from your description and IMO worth specifying).*

There are multiple ways to solve this problem, you can either:

- Use this another version of [`toMap(keyMapper,valueMapper,mergeFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) which requires the third argument, `mergeFunction` - a *function* responsible for resolving duplicates.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = emails.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Function.identity(),
        email -> processEmails(email),
        (list1, list2) -> list1 // or { list1.addAll(list2); return list1} depending on the your logic of resolving duplicates you need
    ));
```

- Make use of the *collector* [`groupingBy(classifier,downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) to preserve all the *emails* retrieved by `processEmails()` that are associated with the same *key* by storing them into a `List`. As a *downstream collector* we could utilize a combination of collectors [`flatMapping()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) and `toList()`.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = emails.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Function.identity(),
                Collectors.flatMapping(email -> processEmails(email).stream(),
                    Collectors.toList())
            ));
```

***Note*** that the later option would make sense only if `processEmails()` somehow generates different results for the same key, otherwise you would end up with a list of repeated values which doesn't seem to be useful.

But what you definitely **shouldn't** do in this case is to use `distinct()`. It'll unnecessarily increase the memory consumption because it eliminates the duplicates by maintaining a `LinkedHashSet` under the hood. It would be wasteful because you're already using `Map` which is capable to deal with duplicated keys.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
Collectors.toMap(Function keyFuntion, Function valueFunction, BinaryOperator mergeFunction)
```

You obviously have to write your own merge logic, a simple mergeFunction could be

```
(x1, x2) -> x1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate emails. The `toMap` version you're using explicitly doesn't allow duplicate keys. Use the `toMap` that takes a merge function. How to merge those `processEmails` results depends on your business logic.

Alternatively, use `distinct()` before collecting, because otherwise you'll probably end up sending some people multiple emails.